# Image analysis/feature extraction using PCA

Tags: python, image-processing, classification, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction

PCA for feature extraction.

Hey all: I read a few papers on using PCA for feature extraction, and then using a neural network to classify the images. But I realized that PCA takes 2D data while convolutional nets take 3D data. For now, I can reshape my images to 2D, and run PCA, but I don't know how to input the result into a convolutional net. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "..convolutional nets take 3D data.." Citation needed.

Answer (score 0):

Convolutional nets are specialised for feature extraction from images, so I don't think you will want any pre-processing of the images (except possibly for mean pixel value subtraction) before giving them as input to the CNN.

Convolutional nets result in a large amount of features, so its possible to reduce the number of features obtained from a CNN using PCA before feeding to a classifier. This is done sometimes in practice since the features obtained from CNNs are ususally highly correlated to one another. PCA can remove these correlations while also lightening the computational load during further processing.

So to answer your question, you can apply PCA to the result of the CNN, but not the other way around. What I believe you read in articles referred to general neural networks (not CNNs) where applying PCA before NN feature extraction is more appropriate.